# How to configure a newsletter subscription in Sitecore 8.2 in CMS Only mode

Tags: wffm, contact-facets, cms-only

I'm trying to figure out the best way to configure the newsletter subscription form built using WFFM which after form submission will send an e-mail to a user with an activation link to confirm the subscription.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361571/how-to-configure-a-newsletter-subscription-with-sitecore-8-1-wffm-and-exm?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) which describes the solution accurately but unfortunately, my project Sitecore license is CMS-only and I'm afraid I cannot use the out of the box solution. I'm using Sitecore 8.2 update 5.

Currently, I'm not able to even add the "Add contact to contact list" save action to the form with error

> This action cannot be added. Your configuration does not support it.

I believe it's caused by the lack of xDb.

Is there any simple way to implement the functionality in CMS-only mode or it has to be a separate mini-project with completely custom development?

Comment: You can upvote and accept one of the answers that best answered your question to help others that will come to this question with their decision. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMS-Only mode you have zero possibilities to achieve your requirements as you cannot use EXM module (which is specifically designed for these kind of scenarios) and missing xDB.

I would recommend three approaches:

1. If client already has Dynamics 365 or MS CRM on prem, you can built easily integration with custom save action in WFFM and save contact or lead there. You can then do automation with workflows and sending emails there.
2. You can built integration with mailchimp or similar service again as custom save action in WFFM
3. Create your own custom solution. For this you would also need SMTP server or use sendgrid or similar services

Answer (score 1):

As you don't have xDB nor EXM it will be difficult (or impossible) with ootb WFFM. I see 2 options:

- fully custom form
- custom save action to send the mail: you could create your own save action to send the mail with the activation link. You have a few options to generate the link: use the formID, the email (with some extra's or I can activate anyone), a combination, or something completely custom again..

In both cases, handling the activation will be custom.